# segmentation fault when using threads - c

Tags: c, pthreads

This is the first time that i am using threads and I started with a simple program. The program takes `n` arguments and creates `n-2` threads. The thing is I get a segmentation fault and I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *
removeBytes (int i, char* argv[])
{
  printf ("%d, %s\n", i, argv[i]);
  return NULL;
}  


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  pthread_t threads[argc - 3];
  int err;
  int i;  
  int *ptr[argc - 3];

  printf ("argc = %d\n", argc);

  for (i = 0; i < argc -3; i++)
    {
      err =
        pthread_create (&(threads[i]), NULL,
                        removeBytes(i+1,&argv[i+1]), NULL);
      if (err != 0)
        {
          printf ("\nCan't create thread: [%d]", i);
        }
      else
        { 
          printf ("\nThread created successfully\n");
        }
    }

  for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; i++)
    {
      pthread_join (threads[i], (void **) &(ptr[i]));
      printf("pthread_join - thread %d",i);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Example: my program is called `mythread` so when I run it `./mythread f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6` the output is:

```
argc = 6

1,f2
Thread created successfully

2,f4
Thread created successfully
3, (null)
```

And why does it take `f2` as `argv[1]` and `f4` as `argv[2]`?

UPDATE:

```
 typedef struct{
    int i;
    char* argv;
  }Data;

  void* removeBytes(void* arg){
    Data* data = (Data*)arg;   
    printf("%d, %s\n",data->i, data->argv);
    free(data);
    return NULL;
  }



  int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Data* data;

    pthread_t threads[argc-3];

    int i;
    int err;
    for(i=0; i < argc-3;i++){
      data = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
      data->i=i+1;
      data->argv=argv[i+1];
      err = pthread_create(&(threads[i]),NULL,removeBytes,data);
      if(err != 0){
        printf("\nCan't create thread %d",i);
      }
      else{
        printf("Thread created successfully\n");
      }
    }  

    return 0;
  }
```

for ./mythread f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 the output is:

5 x "Thread created successfully". It doesn't print i or argvi[i].

Comment: The reason your second program prints nothing is that you've removed the `pthread_join`. The solution you presented in the edit has memory leaks. You can allocate these `struct`s on the stack (e.g. the way I did in my answer, but other options exist as well).

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `pthread_create` correctly :

```
pthread_create (&(threads[i]), NULL,
                        removeBytes(i+1,&argv[i+1]), NULL);
```

Here you're just calling `removeBytes()` and passing the result (`NULL`) as an argument of `pthread_create()`.

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

The third argument should be a pointer to a `void* myThread(void*)` function. If you want to pass arguments to your thread, you should use the `void*` parameter and pass it as the third argument of `pthread_create`.

You could take a look at [`this`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PassingArguments) in order to learn how to use the pthread library.

Also, you probably want to to something like this :

```
typedef struct {
    int i;
    char* argv;
} Data;

void * removeBytes (void* arg)
{
  Data* data = (Data*) arg;
  printf ("%d, %s\n", data->i, data->argv);
  free(data);
  return NULL;
}
```

And then create the thread like this:

```
Data* data = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
data->i = i;
data->argv = argv[i+1];
err = pthread_create (&(threads[i]), NULL, removeBytes, data);
```

Comment: It doesn't print argv and i. It seems that the threads are not accessing removeBytes function... i think

Comment: @MoldovanRazvan [It works](http://pastebin.com/HqGe5c4v) for me with GCC4.8 on Linux, the output is [this](http://pastebin.com/BRzLTX3n). What compiler/system are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
pthread_create (&(threads[i]), NULL,
                    removeBytes(i+1,&argv[i+1]), NULL);
```

You are calling `removeBytes()` instead of passing it as parameter.

Also, You can pass only one argument to thread function. So you need to put multiple arguments in a structure. Something like:

```
struct thread_args {
    int i;
    char *argv;
}

#your main code
struct thread_args *thargs;

for (i = 0; i < argc -3; i++)
{
  thargs = malloc(sizeof(*thargs));
  thargs->i = i+1;
  thargs->argv = argv[i+1];
  err =
    pthread_create (&(threads[i]), NULL,
                    removeBytes, thargs);
  if (err != 0)
    {
      printf ("\nCan't create thread: [%d]", i);
    }
  else
    { 
      printf ("\nThread created successfully\n");
    }
}
#make sure to free up thargs as well.
```

And update thread function as

```
void *removeBytes (void *arg)
{
  int i;
  char *argv;
  struct thread_args *thargs =  (struct thread_args *) arg;
  i = thargs->i;
  argv = thargs->argv;
  printf ("%d, %s\n", i, argv);
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't know why but the ouput is only "Tread created successfully". It doesn't print i and argv[i]. I think it's not accessing removeBytes or something...

Comment: @MoldovanRazvan, have you updated the code correctly? May be you can show us updated code.

Comment: @MoldovanRazvan, when I run the program and give more than 3 args it does print args but not last 2.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in

```
pthread_create (&(threads[i]), NULL,
                    removeBytes(i+1,&argv[i+1]), NULL);
```

Syntax of `pthread_create` is

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

It takes start routine as a callback. In your case, you are calling removeBytes in main thread that is before spawning and returning NULL. So, callback is NULL.

So, modify your removeBytes accordingly as per your need and call

pthread_create (&(threads[i]), NULL,
                        removeBytes, argv[i+1]);

Answer (score 0):

It takes f2 as argv[1] and f4 as argv[2] simply because when you pass &argv[i+1] you actually pass pointer to the (i+1)-th element of the array and you also pass i+1 as index.

So if you have argv equals [mythread, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6] at first you'll get [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6] in removeBytes. And when you're accessing i+1 = 1 element you'll get f2. Next time you'll get [f2, f3, f4, f5, f6]  and i+1 = 2 so you'll get f4